# How to cluster a column with R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe

```
numbers = 1:4
letters = factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
df <- data.frame(numbers, letters)
numbers letters
1       1       a
2       2       b
3       3       c
4       4       d
```

And I want to create a new column clustering the last column:

```
numbers letters
1       1       a      c1
2       2       b      c2
3       3       c      c1
4       4       d      c1
```

Is there a way to do that with R?

Comment: what's the pattern for the clustering? Not immediately clear to me given the sequences of numbers and letters shown. Regardless, to add a new column to your dataframe, look at `transform()` or the `$` operator.

Comment: @Chase I believe the OP is asking how to _obtain_ the clusters, not simply how to assign them to the data frame

Answer (score 2):

R has many different methods for clustering your data. Here is how you would do it with k-means, which is the most popular:

```
# Simulate data
data = data.frame(var1=rnorm(100), var2=rnorm(100), var3=c('a', 'b')[sample(2, 100, replace=T)])

# Convert factor variables to numeric 'dummy' variables
data.num = model.matrix(~ . - 1, data)

# Assign clusters
data$cl = kmeans(data.num, 2)$cluster

# Plot
dev.new(width=4, height=4)
with(data, plot(var1, var2, type='n'))
with(data, text(var1, var2, var3, col=cl))
```

[image]

Here the 2 clusters are identified by color, and are meaningless because the data are normally distributed, but you get the idea...